# Isolate subnet with DD-WRT router

Tags: networking, router, dd-wrt

I have my ISP gateway (which is a regular wifi router) which is `192.168.178.1`. This is connected to a DD-WRT router (using it's WAN port).

I've had this setup for a while now and pretty much the default settings (Connection type Automatic/DHCP) worked. I set the local IP of the dd-wrt router to `192.168.0.1` and set DHCP to use the `192.168.0.xxx` subnet aswell.

This worked fine and I had an  **isolated** subnet. That is: The `192.168.178.xxx` subnet could not access machines on my `192.168.0.1` subnet, including the router, and vice versa.

Now I got a new router, fresh dd-wrt installation, exactly the same settings and subnets, and suddenly I'm able to access `192.168.178.1` from my PC (which is on the dd-wrt subnet).

Which setting is responsible for this, and how do I change that?

Also, the new router displays the ISP router's domain name under `WAN domain name` (`LAN domain name` is empty). The old dd-wrt router did that too, but devices on the network where **not** on that domain (they were on an empty one instead). Now with this router, devices connected to it are automatically on that domain. I would really like to prevent that aswell.

I hope my question is clear enough, and here are some more of my dd-wrt router's settings:

```
Connection Type: Automatic Configuration - DHCP
Hostname: <empty>
Domain name: <empty>
Shortcut Forwarding Engine: Enable
STP: Disable
Local IP Address: 192.168.0.1
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 0.0.0.0
Local DNS: 0.0.0.0
DHCP Type: Server
Start IP Address: 192.168.0.100
DNSMasq for DNS: Enabled
DHCP-Authoritative: Enabled
Forced DNS redirection: Disabled
NTP Client: Enabled
IPv6: Disabled entirely
```

Advanced routing, Switch Config, Networking and Tunnels all on their defaults

Answer (score 0):

To your first question:
It is normal, and by default should have been the same with your old router, that hosts from your 'DD-WRT' network (192.168.0.x) will be able to access hosts in the 'ISP-Router' network (192.168.178.x) as this is part of and required for routing traffic from the 'isolated' network into the internet. Most of the ip addresses in the 'ISP-Router' network, except the  ISP-Router address itself (192.168.178.1), could have been blocked by a firewall on the DD-WRT.
For your second question:
This would require to know the model of your router and the version of the DD-WRT software. Nevertheless, I guess you'll have a better chance for an answer if you ask this question on the DD-WRT Forum.

Comment: Thats kinda weird, because I haven't set any special firewall rules or anything with the old router and it did not let me connect to the other subnet. If it matters: The dd-wrt router is also a VPN client. So technically only the router needs to communicate with the internet. The router is a linksys WRT1900 and DD-WRT is the newest verison (v3.0-r42819 std (03/30/20)). You're probably right about the last part, I'll cross-post it there in a day or two should no answer be found here.

Comment: As most, if not all, DD-WRT router are meant to connect a local LAN to the internet, they are configured to do network address translation (NAT) on the WAN interface. This usually allows all hosts in the local Network (192.168.0.x) to reach all hosts in the public network (192.168.178.1). If, in the past, your router was configured to only forward the traffic of the local network through a VPN gateway, then this will change this behaviour. But this would hardly be called "pretty much the default settings". ;-)

Comment: I see, that does make sense. I do have a firewall that allows traffic only over tun0, but since both VPN and firewall config is 1:1 the same between the routers I assumed that wouldn't matter. So asking differently: What would I need to do in order to not allow the two subnets to communicate? I especially don't want anyone connected to the `192.168.178.1` router to access (or even ping/map/etc.) anything on the `192.168.0.1` router.

Comment: If you didn't configure any port forwarding on your DD-WRT, no host from 192.168.178.x can connect to a host on 192.168.0.x. NAT will usually prevent that.